# $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname {Var}(X)+\operatorname {Var} (Y)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)=\operatorname {Var}(X)+\operatorname {Var} (Y)$

Tags: statistics, variance

$\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname {Var}(X)+\operatorname {Var} (Y)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)=\operatorname {Var}(X)+\operatorname {Var} (Y)$ is also equal to $\operatorname {Var}(X)+\operatorname {Var} (Y)$, What is the main reason ? 
No need of proof. Thanks

Comment: In general: $$\operatorname{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\operatorname {Var}(X)+b^2\operatorname {Var} (Y)+2ab\operatorname {Cov} (X,Y)$$ If $X$ and $Y $ are independent, then the covariance term drops out.

Comment: $\text{Var}(Y)=\text{Var(-Y)}$ if either exist

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is true only if X and Y are independent. In general,$$Var(X\pm Y)= Var(X) + Var (Y)\pm 2Cov(X,Y).$$If $X$ and $Y $ are independent $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and you will get $$Var(X\pm Y)= Var(X) + Var (Y).$$Since you don't want any proof, I'm skipping it.

> Think of variance as being like “norm-squared” and independence as
>   being the orthogonality.

Then you can see that the above mentioned formulas resemble the law of cosines and Pythagorean Theorem respectively.